# C++ : writing to specific index position in std::string

Tags: c++

Hi I am new to community.

I have a question regarding std::string.
Is it possible to write into specific index of string keeping rest of string empty ?

e.g.

```
std::string tempString = ""; 
tempString ->insert(10, "Some String I want to Insert"); 
//index position and string to insert
```

and final answer would be tempString = "__________Some String I want to Insert"

where characters 0 through 9 are uninitialized.

this is possible with char * once memory is allocated.
but is this possible with std::strings ?

Thank you in advance and thank you for having me in this community :)

Comment: Technically, no memory is empty. It should contains something, either meaningful data, garbage, or some placeholder value.

Comment: Thank you for response @Nicky C, I am expecting garbage in that memory. I can enter some other information in that space. However, is it possible with std::string ?

Comment: @RiJnDaeL I am editing your question, with the assumption that *"expecting garbage"* means "uninitialized".

Comment: @DrewDormann  Thank you. Yes I am expecting uninitialized indexes from 0 through 9

Comment: @RiJnDaeL, Just use a `char` array in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some insertion position

```
size_t insertion_position = 10;
```

And some `std::string` or `const char*` to be inserted

```
const char *text = "Some String I want to Insert";
```

This will do it efficiently.

```
std::string tempString( insertion_position, ' ' );
tempString += text;
```

Or as a one liner:

```
std::string tempString = std::string( insertion_position, ' ' ) + text;
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this one.

Comment: std::string tempString( writePos ' ' ); this doesn not seem to be working :(

Comment: this worked, std::string tempString(writePos, ' '); I had to convert writePos to int. Thank a ton for help mate !

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write into specific index of string keeping rest of string [uninitialized] ?

No.

`std::basic_string` is not designed to represent collections of **uninitialized** values.

Comment: can you please re enter the answer you deleted. It seemed to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

check this out, you may be able to use a stringstream instead of cout. Then you can just get the output into a string instead of seeing it dumped on the console

```
// using the fill character
#include <iostream>     // std::cout

int main () {
  char prev;

  std::cout.width (10);
  std::cout << 40 << '\n';

  prev = std::cout.fill ('x');
  std::cout.width (10);
  std::cout << 40 << '\n';

  std::cout.fill(prev);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:
        40
xxxxxxxx40